# postfix MTA seemingly benign I/O Error : postqueue fatal: output write error: Input/output error

Tags: linux, ubuntu, postfix, smtp

I am getting the following message in my syslog exactly every 30 seconds. Everything is working but words like "Fatal" and "Input/output error" cause me an inordinate amount of angst.

```
postfix/postqueue[<procid>]: fatal: output write error: Input/output error
```

Searching logs I can find nothing that points to why this is happening. I found a post from 18 years ago where someone says that it could be ignored but that was 18 years ago and pretty much nothing on the topic since.

If this is a known issue, fine. If not, what is the best way to determine what is causing it?

Hardware is a ESXi 7.0
Ubuntu 22.04
Postfix 3.6.4

All current as of the writing of this note.

Comment: From the docs: *"fatal" is the result of missing files, incorrect permissions, incorrect configuration file settings that you can fix*. You are unlikely to get an answer here, but will get one on the Postfix mailing list.